# How to ignore clicks under a div popup?

Tags: javascript, html, click

I have a popup that can be activated, but everything under it, even though you can no longer see it, is still accepting clicks.

My css for the popup div is

```
#wrapper {
    position:fixed;
    border-top:0px;
    border-bottom:0px;
    z-index:1002;
    overflow:hidden;
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the pop up is up you could try to catch all click event to the windows and do a `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` if you are using jQuery or simply returning false to prevent any other even from being called.

And then you remove this binding when the popup fades.
It would be like putting a black curtain on top of all your events.

Comment: I'm not sure what context to use that in, and with a lot of experimentation I can not get it to have any effect. I'm using a jquery popup that goes on top of a krpano tour.  The map shrinks and grows and all the hot spots work even though the popup is on top of it.

Comment: if you do a `$(window).click(function(e){ e.stopImmediatePropagation();})` I'm not entirely sure, but this could catch all the click event without unbinding then. So that when you close yout popup just unbind this event `$(window).unbind('click')`

Comment: I'm using krpano and it seems to have fixed itself in iOS 6.